# Possible to detect whether a connection came from the netty library, or just a normal socket?

Tags: netty

Weird, and mostly stupid question - but I thought I'd ask on the off chance netty has some underlying system that allows the netty-server to detect whether the client is using netty or not.

I'm asking whether you can detect, from the server (Netty library), whether the connected client is too using the netty libray WITHOUT having to do anything custom like writing my own packet.

Another bundled question. Is it possible to see, from the server, whether the client is using TCP_NODELAY?

I'm asking these questions due to having upgraded my server software to netty. It still accepts, and handles connections from my older non-netty client. I want to send them a warning that they should consider updating so they could benefit from the features of the netty client.

If it's not possible, I'll just create my own version handler. No big deal, just want to see if this already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to both questions is no....